# Intellij : can't remove breakpoint

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I am using Intellij EAP version and it is a lot better than eclipse imo. The problem is that when I am debugging, I can add breakpoints and it works all great but when I remove a breakpoint, the icon on the line does disappear too, but the breakpoint is still there. The debugger still stops at the line even if the breakpoint isn't there anymore.

I get this error: `IllegalStateException: ideToVmBreakpoint.remove(breakpoint) must not be null`

Comment: Can you remove it from Breakpoints window? https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-exception-breakpoints.html ... Also such errors are to be expected in EAP releases. You should use stable version instead of EAP to avoid them.

Comment: I can't use stable version because the structure of my project needs some new features from EAP :( Yes I can delete it from the Breakpoints window but the problem still remains the same.

Comment: Try File>Invalidate cashes/Restart

Comment: The problem happens evry time you add a breakpoint?

Comment: Everytime I add one and remove it afterwards. When I remove all breakpoints and restart the server. Everything is okay. As soon as I have a breakpoint in the code and the server is started, when I remove the breakpoint I get the error

Comment: The invalidate cashes/restart trick did work !

Answer (score 0):

Please file a [YouTrack issue](http://www.youtrack.jetbrains.com) with details for reproducing this problem.